Any evidence of real-world risk from someone else lead-soldering your devices?
I appreciate this is likely neuroticism, but a luthier has recently worked on a couple of guitars of mine. He uses lead-based solder (entirely reasonably), but obviously that involves handling the guitar while soldering, and working on guitars in the same space as soldering generally.
Because I have a young kid, I would like for the risk to be nil. For other devices I'd just give everything a quick wipe down with lead removal wipes and call it good, but I suspect that would have an interesting effect on the finish of a guitar.
Most of the literature or questions I can find with regard to child safety relate to an ongoing source of lead - either someone soldering in the home, paint chips, pipes etc, which I suppose would make it a reasonable assumption that a contamination path of workbench/hands -> guitar -> my hands -> my keyboard/mouse/whatever -> child's hands -> child's mouth is pretty much negligble, but I don't like to assume when it comes to child safety! Kid occasionally plays with my guitars, but not often.
Is there any literature documenting the amount of lead dust/lead that's readily transferred from hands and surfaces to other surfaces relating to soldering?

Is the solder for the electronics inside the guitar? A wipe down with a lightly wetter rag should be enough. The reduction of lead based solders is more about reducing environmental pollution of lead than it is about direct exposure. Note too, leads still everywhere, in water, and in small amounts in the environment. It’s not something you can entirely escape.

Soldering does not vapourise the lead, so exposure to lead dust would be negligible. If it were mercury, then I’d be concerned. Also note that lead free solder removes the issue of lead but replaces it with other toxic metals.

@JarrodChristman Yeah the solder is all internal. You're right, I should just give them a quick wipe down and never think about them again. I alwayas forget there are "background" levels to all the things we panic about, lead, asbestos etc. Obviously intentional/negligent exposure to be avoided, but tiny amounts with reasonable precautions likely won't make the blindest bit of difference! At least we (mostly) got rid of leaded fuels.

@Kartman Which toxic metals are used in SAC305 for example? Or other alloys in common use?

@TimWilliams some solders have antimony, germanium or bismuth. Granted my wording was a bit too broad.

We get these kind of questions all the time. Lead does not vaporize in the temperatures used for soldering. Flux residue is the only concern but can be cleaned up with plain water (...when the device isn't powered, needless to say). Don't let your kid lick on your guitar and it will be fine. It will probably be fine even if they lick on it. There are far worse things to lick on in your home. There are far more dangerous things in your home in general, such as mains connectors, medicine (guns even, if you live in that particular country). Etc etc. Focus on things that are actually dangerous.

@Lundin Yeah, I know it's not hot enough to vaporise (I've done bits of soldering in my own past, with leaded and unleaded solders), it was more the contact/contamination that I had concerns around. I've since given the guitars a wipe down with a (very mildly!) damp cloth which is almost certainly overkill, but there we are!

According to Agency for Toxic Substances and Disease Registry of US Government,

Dermal exposure plays a role for exposure to organic lead among workers, but is not considered a significant pathway for the general population.

Organic lead may be absorbed directly through the skin.
Organic lead (tetraethyl lead) is more likely to be absorbed through
the skin than inorganic lead.
Dermal exposure is most likely among people who work with lead or
materials that contain lead.


(my italicization)
To clarify - Lead in solder is not organic lead, it's metallic lead.
The limit of for considering lead poisoning in children is 3.5µg/dL blood. With the density of elemental lead, that's one 42µm sphere of pure lead (that's a visible amount of lead) pr dL of blood. A child has 0.80-0.90dL/kg blood volume. Solder is not pure lead, but typically 30-40% by weight. So multiply volume by >2x-3x. Easily visible amounts of solder!
So, it's not healthy to chew solder joints - surprise surprise. As long as you're not getting acute lead poisoning, it's a question of decreasing the accumulated exposure during life.

Regarding your suggested contamination path - There are two factors - probability of contamination from A to B, and the amount of lead that can be transferred. As a simple model - consider a compound interest type comparison - we assign some sort of probability to cross-contamination from each point to the next - that would be that probability to the power of 5. If you chose 50/50 as to get any lead from A to B - the probability would be a hair over 3%. Then you need to consider how much lead got transferred.
It's easy to see that you're not able to transfer 100% of the lead during each probable transfer. That <100% transfer factor also compounds the same way.
Needless to say - of the very little lead that you were able to pick from the original exposure - very little is left, and it's unlikely to get all the way to the end of the chain.
It's impossible for someone here on an Electrical Engineering site to give you conclusive evidence to say there will never be 0% chance, 0% lead left, and in the end the risk evaluation will be completely your subjective decision. I would be more concerned about lead paint or eating too much tuna.

Officially, according to the (US) EPA, there is no identified minimum safe level for lead. Levels thought okay in the past have been revised downward.

EPA and the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) agree
that there is no known safe level of lead in a child's blood. Taking
action to reduce these exposures can improve outcomes. Lead is harmful
to health, especially for children.

So if you want the risk due to lead to be "nil", the exposure to lead should also be "nil".
Of course that's impossible, lead is an element and is present in some amount just about everywhere,  and pursuing it would likely lead to unintended consequences that are worse than taking "reasonable" risks, but there you go.
Personally, I would have no great concern unless there was actual contact with the solder (especially mixed with eating acidic foods), or if solder paste was present. But my risk tolerance for my progeny may be different from yours.

According to the CDC, 20 to 70% of lead ingested into the body is absorbed, with children absorbing more. Lead can also be inhaled, although I don't think that would be the case for you. Unless if your child doesn't wash their hands, they should be fine. If the soldered connection is outside of the guitar, you might want to ask your luthier to use lead free solder as it doesn't cause lead poisoning. The downsides are that it is more expensive and it doesn't have joints as nice as leaded solder. But again, it is still better than lead poisoning.

The price difference is pretty much zip these days.  More likely the luthier has a roll of 60/40 that's like a decade old.

Lead-free solder needs a higher temperature meaning more nasty crap gets vaporized - not lead but the harmful flux. Generally RoHS solder is considered less healthy to use during the soldering procedure than leaded solder for this reason. Asking the guitar shop to use lead-free solder is uninformed. Anyway, the key here is: don't lick on the guitar, leaded solder or not. You shouldn't be licking on most home appliances...
